# Unstable CPU usage

Tags: c, cpu-usage

I am currently writing application in C in which I intend to simulate CPU load in ubuntu less than 100%. I used factorials algorithm to stress my CPU and `nanosleep` function to regulate CPU usage. The goal is to have steady CPU usage with reasonable tolerance which can be varied in steps, i.e. 20%, 30% etc. The problem is when I start my app I get bouncing load 45-53% which where I want to have load with 50% CPU usage. Because of my research I need to get stable CPU usage where I calculate response time by tracking timestamp between two executions.

**EDIT** I'm using VmWare Workstation with Ubuntu 14.04 VM for my research.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval t1;

    int milisec = 5; // length of time to sleep, in miliseconds
    struct timespec req = {0};
    req.tv_sec = 0;
    req.tv_nsec = milisec * 1000000L;

    FILE *file; 
    file = fopen("trace.txt", "w");
    //int j = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);        
        int i;
        int res = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < 580000; i++)
        {   
            res = res*i;    
        }



        nanosleep(&req, (struct timespec *)NULL);


        fprintf(file, "%llu%llu\n", (unsigned long long)t1.tv_sec, (unsigned long long)t1.tv_usec);
        fflush(file);
        //j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm, this isn't `C++`, you 'd better change tag to `C`.

Comment: `which can be varied in steps, i.e. 20%, 30% etc`: How is that supposed to happen ? You don't fetch any command-line arguments.

Comment: And your loop to 580000 will probably be optimized away by the compiler, unless you add the switch telling him not to do so. What compiler ?

Comment: Also consider hardware: modern CPUs will change clock rate depending on load. These days they can switch such states quite fast.

Comment: @kebs I planned to do it manually, because of simplicity by changing the number range in the for loop. How can I do it with switch? I use Ubuntu with gcc compiler

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on it - seems pretty good in my light testing.  Basic idea's to use `getrusage` to track how much CPU time the program's had, divide that by wallclock elapsed time, and yield if it's over the target ratio.  You can see if it gives more stable results than your own code.

(NOTE: the question was tagged C++ and not C initially... code can trivially be ported to C)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void usage_exit(const char* argv0)
{
    std::cerr << "usage " << argv0 << " <target>\n"
        "   spin burning <target> proportion of one CPU (e.g. 0.5 = 50%)\n";
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        usage_exit(argv[0]);
    std::istringstream iss(argv[1]);
    double target;
    if (!(iss >> target))
        usage_exit(argv[0]);

    struct timeval start, now;
    gettimeofday(&start, 0);

    struct rusage usage;
    while (getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage) == 0)
    {
        gettimeofday(&now, 0);
        double running = usage.ru_utime.tv_sec + usage.ru_utime.tv_usec * 1E-6 +
                         usage.ru_stime.tv_sec + usage.ru_stime.tv_usec * 1E-6;
        double elapsed = now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec +
                         now.tv_usec * 1E-6 - start.tv_usec * 1E-6;
        if (running / elapsed > target)
            pthread_yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to run the code. When i enter `./{filename} 0.5` I get 100% cpu usage. Same result is with any other value

Comment: @j4l3 hmmm... I guess that's because there's nothing competing for the CPU on your box, so the kernel just keeps running this program.   My assumption was that you wanted this program to use whatever-proportion of the CPU time, so some other program would be capped at getting whatever's left - but your research is just to have this one program churning CPU for its own sake?  Perhaps for observing consequences to battery life or heat?  If so, using some nanosleep value instead of yield makes sense; tricky thing is tuning the duration: I think it likely to be important - maybe trial & error?

Comment: In my research I'm testing multiple VMs within VmWare Workstation. I'm observing stolen cpu time between two or more VMs. In the beginning I want to test it on one VM. I want to start one application with certain fixed CPU usage and then start another one which starts with 10%, then after some time increases to 20%, 30%.. and so on to the 100%

Comment: @j4l3 that's an usual twist... if you've tried replacing yield with a range of nanosleep periods while leaving the rusage running/elapsed logic as is, I'm afraid I'm not sure what else to suggest....